# Marshalling from C# to a DLL with a TCHAR** x[] parameter

Tags: c#, .net, dll, marshalling, dllimport

I am trying to call a Win32 DLL from some C#. The DLL function is declared as follows:

```c
extern "C" __declspec(dllexport) UINT foo(TCHAR** list[], int& listSize, TCHAR* error);
```

In C#, I declare the external function like so:

```cs
[DllImport("foo.dll", CallingConvention = CallingConvention.Cdecl, CharSet = CharSet.Auto)]
static extern uint foo(StringBuilder[] list, ref int listSize, StringBuilder error);
```

My problem has to do with the *list* parameter, which is an array of StringBuilder classes.

Some test code where I call the DLL function is as follows:
(Note: I realise that there are boundary checks missing, etc. At this stage, I am just trying to get things working).

```cs
// allocate a buffer for a possible error message being returned
StringBuilder error = new StringBuilder(1000);

// allocate buffers for the list of strings returned
StringBuilder[] list = new StringBuilder[10];
for (int i = 0; i < 10; i++)
{
    list[i] = new StringBuilder(1000);
}

int listSize = list.Length;

uint result = foo(list, ref listSize, error);
```

Passing the StringBuilder as a buffer for the *error* parameter, works fine. I can set its contents in the DLL as follows:

```cpp
_tcscpy(error, _T("Something went wrong");
```

When the C# call to *foo* returns, the *string error* variable has the text we set it to in the DLL.

But, I cannot work out how to marshal the *StringBuilder[] list* parameter.

In the C++, I am able to set the contents of the *list* array:

```cpp
_tcscpy((*list)[0], _T("First item")); 
// and so on...
```

And, even though there is no crash that occurrs due to any possible problematic marshalling, the *list* in the C#, when the call to *foo()* returns, does not contain any of the strings we set in the C++.

I'm guessing that the problem is with the *DllImport* and how I've declared the *list* parameter should be marshalled.

By the way, the example DLL has a matching function which one would then call to deallocate the "TCHAR** list" returned by the example *foo* shown above.

Comment: `TCHAR** list[]`? Do you have an array of strings, or an array of an array of strings?

Comment: An array of pointers which point to pointers to TCHARs. Confusing, I know.

Comment: So why did you define the managed signature as `StringBuilder[]`? This is equivalent of `TCHAR **` I guess. But neither will work in your case :).

Comment: Well, maybe my definition is wrong too. It's all related to my problem, that I'm trying to get working.

Comment: For the error parameter, StringBuilder works well, and that's a TCHAR*. So, I assumed that for TCHAR** list[], that StringBuilder would be correct.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

OK, I have found a solution to my question. It looks like the answer lay in *IntPtr*. The C function created and returned an array of string in "TCHAR** list[]".

First, I changed the declaration in C# to:

```cs
[DllImport("foo.dll", CallingConvention = CallingConvention.Cdecl, CharSet = CharSet.Auto)]
static extern uint foo(out IntPtr[] list, ref int listSize, StringBuilder error);
```

Then, when the call to the DLL returned, I needed to extract the strings from the array:

```cs
string[] returnedList = new string[listSize];
IntPtr[] ptrArray = new IntPtr[listSize];

Marshal.Copy(list, ptrArray, 0, listSize);

for (int i = 0; i < listSize; i++)
{
    returnedList[i] = Marshal.PtrToStringAuto(ptrArray[i]);
}
```

And that resulted in getting back the array of strings from the C DLL.

Comment: If this works then you have high odds for leaking memory, not getting the string buffers released.  Test this by pinvoking the function a million times and make sure that memory usage doesn't blow up.

Comment: The DLL has an associated function that the user needs to call to free the "TCHAR** list[]" returned by the aforementioned _foo_ example.

Comment: Do mention such details in a question.  That skips having us to wonder how such an api function could possibly work as intended and produces wrong answers that are not useful to anybody.

Answer (score 0):

I have not done this in a while, but you should try the follwing in order to marshal the array *list* correctly:

Add a
`[MarshalAs(UnmanagedType.LPArray, ArraySubType.LPTStr, SizeParamIndex=1)]` 
attribute to *list*, and you should add an `out`, since the data is allocated in C++ code.